# Explain why an information desk area can feature self-service machines

Tags: meaning-in-context

A freelancer who is a native speaker wrote the text. I don't understand how an information desk area can feature self-service machines. To me, an information desk area is supposed to feature an information desk. Can you explain the logic?

> Continuing past the café, the area that once housed adult non-fiction
> books has been transformed into **an information desk area, featuring
> self-service machines** for library visitors.

[image]

Comment: I would say you don't need a physical, staffed desk to create a modern self-service area, and it may make sense to continue using the word 'desk' to make it clearer to library users that the new area provides the services that the old type desk arrangement did. However, you could also omit the word 'desk'.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but what about my question about the information desk area **featuring** self-service machines?

Comment: What is your question? An information desk area can feature multiple items, e.g. comfortable chairs, a coffee vending machine, self-service machines, free pencils, whatever.

Comment: @newbieforever Yes, that sounds better to me, but as James K says in his answer to your other question about reimagining the library, it's fancy words to express a simple idea. In this case you could replace "featuring" with "with" without loss of meaning  In my local library, for example, there is an information desk with a member of staff to answer questions and make reservations and there are self service machines that read the bar codes in the books for checking books in and out automatically.

Comment: **Self-service machines** are usually dispensers of beverages and snacks, which would be normally found in the cafeteria area. Perhaps the text refers to computers to look things up, or devices to check books out and in, as Michael Harvey mentioned. Although they would normally be called **devices** not **machines**.  You could say "... with scanning devices for checking books in and out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That area of the library does have an information desk and self-service machines.  An area with an information desk doesn't always feature self-service machines, but the one in the picture does. There is also an information desk.

The use of the word "feature" is somewhat odd, but I've adopted it.  It's not wrong.  It suggest that these are an important addition to the area, but not essential. For example, we might say "The film features Tom Cruise." It means that Tom Cruise is an important part of the film, but not every film has to have Tom Cruise in it!

I'd understand that 20 years ago you would take books to the Enquiry Desk to check them out or return them.  Now that is done by self-service. The information desk is therefore much smaller than the old Enquiry Desk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think it would be better to say that continuing past the café, the area that once housed adult non-fiction books has been transformed into **a service area, featuring an information desk and some self-service machines**?

Comment: That's good English too.

Answer (score 1):

The word "feature" as a verb doesn't describe what a feature *is*, but what features something *has*.

[Merriam-Webster][1] defines it:

> **3 b :** to have as a characteristic or feature
> *a menu featuring many options*

In your context, the Information Desk Area *has* self-service machines *as a feature*.

It is correct as written by the freelancer.
[1]: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feature